# How to remove a known smooth signal with known location and unknown amplitude from an unknown signal?

Tags: fourier-transform, python, continuous-signals

I have a known smooth complex signal $f(x)$:

[image: f(x)]

It's added to an unknown complex signal $g(x)$ after being multiplied to an
unknown complex amplitude $A = u+iv$ (this image is just for illustration, in reality the amplitude of $f$ is ~1e3 greater):
[image: g(x) and g(x) + Af(x)]

How do I find $A$?

The method I've tried is minimizing the number and amplitude of modes in their difference:

```
def cost_func(A): 
    u = A[0]
    v = A[1]
    diff = g_plus_f - f * (u+1j*v)
    diff_abs = np.abs(np.fft.fft(diff))[:100]
    diff_abs[diff_abs<1e-4] = 0
    return(np.sum(diff_abs)**0.2)
```

This works to some extent, but when the amplitude of $Af$ and $g$ become similar the optimization stops:

[image: result]

How can I improve this further?

(Python solutions preferred)

Comment: Could you provide the signals (pref. in Python ;-) and amplitude you used for your example?

Answer (score 4):

To put your problem into equation, you are trying to solve:
$$h = g + A f, \tag{1}\label{1}$$
with $f$ and $h$ known/observed signals, and $g$ and $A$ are unknowns that you are trying to estimate.

Without any further assumptions, you cannot solve this equation as there are too many unknowns. For any $A$, you can always find a $g$ that will verify \eqref{1}, and vice versa.

However if you assume for example that $g$ and $f$ are *uncorrelated*, i.e. $f^{H}g \approx 0$, then you have:
$$ \begin{aligned}
f^{H}h =& f^{H}g + A f^{H}f\\
\approx& A f^{H}f
\end{aligned}
$$
and:
$$ A_{\text{estimate}} = \frac{f^{H}h}{f^{H}f}$$
$$ g_{\text{estimate}} = h - \frac{f^{H}h}{f^{H}f}f.$$

This is similar to a [matched filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matched_filter), somewhat simplified here cause we already know the position of $f$.

Note that plugging back into \eqref{1}, we get:
$$ A_{\text{true}} = A_{\text{estimate}} - \frac{f^{H}g}{f^{H}f}$$
and:
$$ g_{\text{true}} = g_{\text{estimate}} + \frac{f^{H}g}{f^{H}f}f,$$

so the error term and the quality of your estimate depend on how true the uncorrelatedness assumption ($f^{H}g \approx 0$ or at least $|f^{H}g| \ll f^{H}f)$ is.

You could derive other (potentially non-linear) estimates if you had other assumptions about your signal $g$, such as sparsity, smoothness, a prior distribution, etc.